# Rails associations and MVC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

in my Rails app I have a User model and a Team model, linked through a User_Team model.

What I'm trying to do is to ask Rails to validate and create a new user only if the params used to create it come with a valid team_code param.

Basically I need to:

1. check the Team table
2. look if a team with the provided team_code exists
3. only in this case allow the creation of the user
4. link the user to the team

Which is the best way to do this?  Where should I put the logic?  In the controller? In the user validation model?

Even just a few hints would be helpful!

**UPDATE #1**
The team_code is an attribute of the Team model.  Teams are created previously (not during user creation).  I need that each user - in order to be created - has an existing team to enter at user creation time.

Thanks,
Augusto

Comment: Hi. You haven't said what the 'team_code' is - is it an attribute on the Team model? Do you want people to be able to create a team at the same time as creating a User, or do you just want them to select an existing team? Do you want your validation to basically just check that each user has at least one team associated with them?

Comment: Hi Roberto, thanks for your notes.  I just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation logic belongs in the model. Here's how I'd do it:

```
class User
  belongs_to :team
  attr_accessor :team_code
  def team_code
    @team_code ? @team_code : (team ? team.team_code : nil)
  end
  def team_code= (value)
    @team_code = value
    self.team  = Team.where('team_code = ?', value).first
  end
  validates_presence_of :team
  validates_each :team_code do |record, attr, value|
    record.errors.add attr, 'does not exist' if !value.blank? && !team
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jeremy, your solution is clever and simple!